# How to get inside a view the metadata of a generic param of a IEnumerable<> Model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If I have a view with a Model declared as `@model IEnumerable<MyValueObject>`, how is the best way to have access to the metadata from MyValueObject ?

I cannot use templates so, iterating in my collection and calling a template with the Model MyValueObject isn't a option because the collection is consumed directly by a third party helper here. Think in a helper that render a grid, and all I can do here is to specify format and other properties by each property (column) which I want to recover from medatadata of MyvalueObject.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(m => item, ViewData);
}
```

Comment: I was expecting anothers alternatives instead "ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression()". I think nobody will try to suggest more ways now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Luciano, do you want me to delete my answer? You didn't stipulate in your question that you wanted a solution other than ModelMetadata.From...

Comment: maybe I was harsh in my reply, sorry. Please, keep this answer. I haven't addressed this expection it would stimulate discussions and maybe solution variations.

Comment: It's okay I don't mind deleting if you are looking for a different answer. Might get you more attention if others see no replies.